# Проблема с настройкой VPN WireGuard

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, vpn, wireguard

Мне нужно создать VPN такой, чтобы

1. У клиентов были стические IP адреса.
2. Клиенты могли взаимодействовать друг с другом и сервером,
3. Клиенты могли выходить в интернет из-под VPN.
4. Также, хотелось бы настроить собственный DNS и приватные домены (обрабатываемые NginX).

Конфигурационные сервера у меня такой:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1/24, fd86:ea04:1115::1/64
ListenPort = 5555
PrivateKey = xxxxx

[Peer]
PublicKey = xxxxx
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
```

А это конфигурации клиента:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = xxxxx
ListenPort = 5555
Address = 10.0.0.2/32
DNS = 8.8.8.8

[Peer]
PublicKey = xxxxx
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
```

Но при попытке загрузить конфигурации сервера через `wg setconf wg0 /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf` я получаю такую ошибку:

```
Line unrecognized: `Address=10.0.0.1/24,fd86:ea04:1115::1/64'
Configuration parsing error
```

Поэтому я закомментировал ту строку. Но это вероятно заставляет WG выбирать себе и клиентам случайные IP адреса.

Для запуска WireGuard я выполняю такие команды:

```
ip link add dev wg0 type wireguard
ip address add dev wg0 10.0.0.1/24
ip link set up dev wg0
```

После, команда `wg` даёт такой вывод:

```
interface: wg0
  public key: xxxxx
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 5555

peer: xxxxx
  endpoint: <my IP address>:6228
  allowed ips: 0.0.0.0/0
  latest handshake: 2 minutes, 11 seconds ago
  transfer: 26.02 KiB received, 248 B sent
```

С клиента (моя MacOS с WireGuard GUI) у меня получается подключиться, но:

- Нет соединения с интернетом. Я даже не могу пинговать сервер  по глобальному адресу, хотя по приватному `10.0.0.1` получается.
- Я могу подключиться к VPN даже если укажу в конфиге клиента другой порт. Думаю, это значит, что он не подключается на самом деле.

Как мне заставить WireGuard работать нужным образом? И что не так с моими конфигами??

<sub>PS. На сервере нет ни `iptables`, ни файерволов, так что это не может быть проблемой. Также, в файле `/etc/sysctl.conf` я указал `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` и `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1`, и выполнил `systemctl restart systemd-networkd`.

Версии ПО. ОС: `Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS`, Kernel: `4.15.0-20-generic`, WG: `wireguard-tools v1.0.20200206`.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итак, за несколько дней, ночей и убитых серверов, я наконец разобрался со всем `:)`

- Во-первых, стоит заметить, что утилиты `wg` и `wg-quick` работают с конфигами по-разному (видимо, `wg` не поддерживает последние форматы конфига). Поэтому вместо `wg setconf wg0 /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf` я стал использовать `wg-quick` посредством `systemctl`.
- Во-вторых, моё добавление `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` к файлу `/etc/sysctl.conf` не заработало даже выполняя `systemctl daemon-reload ; systemctl restart systemd-networkd`. Мне надо было ещё отправить конфиг в ядро ОС командой `sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`. Это наконец позволило клиентам взаимодействовать друг с другом и обращаться к интернету из-под VPN.
- Стоит заметить, что для всех запией `Address` лучше указывать маску подсети в 32 бита, т.к она обозначает конкретный IP адрес, а не диапазон.
- Также, мне удалось настроить собственный DNS используя BIND9 для создания кастомного домена в своей сети. И поднять NginX с прослушиванием по адресу в локальной сети и дополнительной проверкой IP отправителя для ограничения доступа только для клиентов VPN'а.

В итоге, конфиги у меня получились такие:

**Сервер**

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1/32
ListenPort = 5555
PrivateKey = ___some_private_key___

# Это нужно только если на сервере установлен `ufw`
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = ___some_public_key___
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.1/32
```

**Client**

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ___some_private_key___
ListenPort = 5555
Address = 10.0.0.1/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = ___some_public_key___
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/24
Endpoint = ___some_ip_address__:5555
```